# Retrieving issues from jira conditoinally

Tags: http, plsql, jira

I am using a sql http request to retrieve issues from JIRA , so far I can retrieve chosen number of issues according to the assignee name or reporter. 
My problem now that I can not retrieve issues according to the creation field (date when the issues has been created) or othe custom field, I am receiving error : 
**Unrecognized field !** 
My approach was to play around with this part of the code :

```
**lv_json_request := '{'
                                            ||'"jql": "assignee='||:P9_ASSIGNEE||'",'
                                            ||'"startAt": '||NVL(:P9_STARTAT,0)||','
                                            ||'"maxResults": '||:P9_MAXRESULTS
                                            ||'}';**
```

You can find below the whole pl/sql block , it works fine with the current situation .

```
DECLARE
  http_req utl_http.req;
    http_resp utl_http.resp;    
    lv_json_request VARCHAR2(32767); 
    lc_response CLOB;
    lv_response VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    lv_json_request := '{'
                                            ||'"jql": "assignee='||:P9_ASSIGNEE||'",'
                                            ||'"startAt": '||NVL(:P9_STARTAT,0)||','
                                            ||'"maxResults": '||:P9_MAXRESULTS
                                            ||'}';

    UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/oracle/ora11/owm/wallets/oracle', 'apex4wallet');
    http_req:= utl_http.begin_request
                            ( url => 'https://rb-wam.bosch.com/tracker/rest/api/2/search'
                            , method => 'POST'                      
                            );
    utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Authorization', 'Basic '||:F_JIRA_TOKEN_REST); 
    utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(lv_json_request));
    utl_http.write_text(http_req, lv_json_request);
    http_resp:= utl_http.get_response(http_req);
    -- read data from response  
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_text(http_resp, lv_response);
            HTP.PRN(lv_response);
            lc_response := lc_response || TO_CLOB(lv_response);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
            utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
    END;    
    -- log details
    --DELETE webservice_log;
    INSERT INTO webservice_log (seq_id,clob_response,clob_request) VALUES (sqe_Webservice_Log.NEXTVAL,lc_response,TO_CLOB(lv_json_request));        

    --HTP.P(lc_response);
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: If you are already in the DB, why don't you do things there?

Comment: Hello , the approach that I have mentioned works. I googled about jql , it is possible to retrieve issues according to the creation date by using the field name created.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to your lv_json_request statement:

```
"createdDate<='||:P9_CREATED||'"
```

using any valid operator instead of "<=", depending on your needs.